# How to Amend an image tag in an SVG tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How would you go about amending an image tag within an SVG using Javascript?

So I have an image stored in a SVG, like so:

```
<svg height="666px" width="666px" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
 <image id="changingImage" href="phone.png" x="69.0802" y="344.9714" height="28" width="28"></image>
</svg>
```

So the suggestion I got from online and tried in my script was grabbing the ID and updating the source like so:

```
document.getElementById("changingImage").src = "phone2.png";
```

That didn't work, so I thought about it a bit and realized that the image tags in SVG don't use SRC, they use HREF. So I tried the following, but it still didn't work:

```
document.getElementById("changingImage").href = "phone2.png";
```

Anyone know how to amend images within an SVG using javascript, or got any ideas about what I could try?

Comment: you may need to use the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look that up!

Comment: It bloody worked !

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post the answer with the syntax for anyone who might have the same problem. The suggestion from user **@enxaneta** worked, using `setAttribute`. Here's the syntax based on the example above.

```
document.getElementById("changingImage").setAttribute("href", "phone2.png");
```